# Script for running a cmd command in a conditional loop

Tags: windows, cmd

First of all, i am new to writing scripts.
I need to prepare a script that will basically run my job with a date parameter. The command i use looks like this:

`s start X N TST 2019-08-31`

Job for the next month can only start once the previous one is done, so based on the return code value i would run:

`s start X N TST 2019-09-30`

- each one for the last day of a month (for 3 years total 2017-19).

Is there a way to automate it so I do not have to check if the job is done and run the command manually?

Comment: ok, so first things first. Which is it? `cmd`, `shell` or `powershell` if you are unsure, hover over the tags you provided for some clarity.

Comment: Done, Thank you, It's cmd.

Comment: So it is `cmd.exe` as used on a Windows OS?

Comment: Yes exactly, im using cmd to run the command.

Comment: Do you have a list of dates populated in a file yet by any chance?

Comment: I do not but it is a possibility

Comment: ok, so you'd need to populate the dates as no system would know which dates you want. Put them in list form, in other words one date per line. You can then run a for loop. `for /f "usebackq" %i in ("C:\your\filename.txt") do s start X N TST %i`

Comment: Thank you, i will test that in near future (possibly tomorrow since I am on a business trip) and will come back with the result ! Thanks a lot! :)

Could you possibly break down the loop you've provided so i can understand what exactly is happening?

Comment: Ok now i understand the syntax, tested on DEV and it seems to be working fine. Thank you very much, You sir just made my life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through each date, you would need to give some input source to the `for` loop, which will assign a metavariable to each result and perform an action with it:

From cmdline:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in ("C:\your\filename.txt") do s start X N TST %i
```

In a `batch-file` simply double up the `%`:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("C:\your\filename.txt") do s start X N TST %%i
```

You can run `for /?` from `cmd` to see all the relevant help, but in shot the above explained.

`for /f` creates the loop, `usebackq` simply allows us to double quote a file with path in this instance (necessary, if the path name or file name has one or more spaces, but "best practice" to always quote path and file names),
`%i` is the metavariable assigned to each result
`("..")` is where we generate out metavariable results from, in this case the file,
`do` an action in this case `s start X N TST %i`